# Regular expression using (a|b)

Tags: regex, regular-language

My code for entering the regular expression and find the minimum length of the string. e.g:`ab*(ab)+` So the minimum length of the string for this regular expression to be matched is 3.But my code causes problems while checking for `(a|b)`. It gives a segmentation fault. However it runs fine for `(a|b)*`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

 void main()
 {
struct node *regexp=null,*language=null;
char d,lokahead;
int i,j,k,countl=0,mincount=0,count=0;
printf("\nEnter the regular expression:");
for(i=0;;i++)
{
    scanf("%c",&d);
    if (d=='.')
        break;
    push(&regexp,d);
}
//traverse(&regexp);
mincount=check(&regexp);
printf("\nThe minimum size of the language should be %d",mincount);
printf("\nEnter the language:");
for(i=0;;i++)
{
    scanf("%c",&d);
    if (d=='.')
        break;
    countl++;
    push(&language,d);
}
}

---queue.h

#define null 0

 struct node{
        char data;
        struct node *next;
       };

 void push(struct node **head,char d);
 char pop(struct node **head);

int check(struct node **head)
{
    struct node *k;
    char d,d1;
    int count=0,mincount=0;
    if(*head!=null)
    {
        k=*head;
        while(k!=null)
        {
            d=k->data;
            if ((d>=97 && d<=122) || (d>=65 && d<=90))
            {
                k=k->next;
                d1=k->data;
                //printf("\n%c %d",d,mincount);
                if ((d1>=97 && d1<=122) || (d1>=65 && d1<=90) || (d1=='(') || (d1=='|'))
                    mincount++;
                /*if (d1=='+')
                {
                    mincount++;
                    k=k->next;
                }*/
            }
            else if (d=='*')
            {
                k=k->next;
            }
            else if (d=='+')
            {
                mincount++;             
                k=k->next;
            }
            else if (d=='(')    //checks for open (
            {
                k=k->next;  
                while(k->data!=')') //checks till close )
                {
                    if (k->data!='|')   //count the characters inside (...)                 
                        count++;
                    if ((k->data)=='|')         //counts the case (..a|b..) as 1 character
                        k=k->next;
                    k=k->next;      
                }
                printf("\nElements inside bracket %d",count);
                k=k->next;      //proceeds pointer so that we leave (...)
                if (k->data=='+')   //checks if we have (...)+ then the minimum charcters should be the number of char
                    mincount+=count;//inside the ()
                count=0;        
                k=k->next;      //increase the pointer to next element
            }
            else if (d=='|')
            {
                k=k->next;
                if (k->data!='+' || k->data!='*' || k->data!='(')
                    mincount++;
            }
        }
    }
    return mincount;
}
```

Output:

```
paku@ubuntu:./regex
Enter the regular expression:ab*(ab)+.

Elements inside bracket 2

The minimum size of the language should be 3

Enter the language:aab.
```

Output 2:

```
paku@ubuntu:./regex
Enter the regular expression:ab*(a|b).

Segmentation fault.(core dumped)
```

Comment: I think you need to show more code - what created the tree? Is enough space allocated?

Comment: Yes!I hope so..But i don't know why it crashes if there is no * or + after ( ).

Answer (score 1):

As its giving segmentation fault your code is accessing the memory which is out of scope for this program . Check pointers

Comment: Yes checked it but the problem is in case of ( ). anything inside a bracket if not followed by a * or + gives segmentation fault.

Comment: give complete code . will try from my side add more comments too